# AngularJS select ng-model

Tags: angularjs

I use the following select statement:

```
<select ng-model="vm.institution" ng-options="c as c.institutionName for c in vm.institutionsOfUser"></select>
```

In my model, the institution is stored but what I will have is to onyl store the id of the institution selected (and contained in vm.institutionsOfUser-> id)

Is there a possibility to do this?

Comment: Take a look at the doc link, its well explained here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#-select-as-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change ngOptions a little `c.id as c.institutionName for c in vm.institutionsOfUser`:

```
<select ng-model="vm.institution" 
        ng-options="c.id as c.institutionName for c in vm.institutionsOfUser"></select>
```

This will bind model to institution id instead of entire object.